# git reset remote head

Tags: git, rollback, git-push, git-reset

My colleague has pushed some commits to our working branch by mistake and now I want to rollback to a previous commit both locally and remotely.

I use reset --hard to the selected commit, the HEAD in my local branch moves to the selected commit and then I use

git push -f origin working_branch:working_branch

to push the HEAD
but I get  denying non-fast-forward error.

How should I rollback to the selected commit both locally and remotely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you can revert that commit with `git revert` command - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert. `git revert` creates another commit that reverts changes. Also pushing with `--force` is not safe as you may override tree that someone already fetched.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I finally did.

Comment: no problem, btw it it helped - you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use git reset --hard HEAD~1 to remove the latest commit and then do

git push origin master --force

to push to the server

Comment: This is what I tried first but git denied to push to the remote server. I got denying non-fast-forward error.